# Capture Subdomain Conversion Sources (Goals) in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have the main domain (`www.example.com.br`) where it receives all visitors (organic, paid, direct).

But where the registration is done is `dashboard.example.com.br`, but the origin does not correctly capture where the registration was made (organic, paid, direct).

Is there any way to be able to capture the origins in the subdomain?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to add this subdomain in GA and GTM: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469?hl=en

Well, really, this article encompasses it completely if you want to read about all the caviats of it:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

But generally what I do is go to GTM and add the domains to the GA settings variable in the auto link domains field. After that, I go to GA, and set the referral exclusion list, listing all the subdomains and domains in it. To make sure this traffic's attribution doesn't get overwritten with referral, but preserve the original source and medium dimensions. Here's the instruction: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830

Note that I presume here that you're using the same GTM container and the same GA property to track stuff across the domains you need to link. Otherwise, it's on a completely different complexity level.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick response.

In case I'm using the same domain, only the registration is a subdomain